# Pass react router path in onClick function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, url-routing

I have a React form which has the following form submission button:

```
<Link 
    className="btn btn-secondary btn-width-200 search-submit" 
    to={{pathname: '/booking/search', query: this.state.filters}}>
     Search

</Link>
```

In the above `link` I want to call a function `handleSubmit(evt)` on button click.

```
handleSubmit(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    this.setState({form_submitted: true});
}

<Link className="btn btn-secondary btn-width-200 search-submit" to={{pathname: '/booking/search', query: this.state.filters}} onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>Search</Link>
```

But the following ignores the `to={{pathname: '/booking/search', query: this.state.filters}}` and just takes `handleSubmit` function into consideration

Is there anyway to add `to={{pathname: '/booking/search', query: this.state.filters}}` to the `handleSubmit` function? Or is there anyway to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This  :

```
import {Link} from 'react-router';

handleSubmit(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    this.setState({form_submitted: true});
}

<Link 
    className="btn btn-secondary btn-width-200 search-submit" 
    to={{pathname: '/booking/search', query: this.state.filters}}>
     Search

</Link>
```

Can be replaced by  :

```
import {browserHistory} from 'react-router';

handleSubmit(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    this.setState({form_submitted: true});
    return this.redirect('/booking/search', this.state.filters);

}

redirect(to, query) {
   browserHistory.push({pathname: to, query})

}

<a
    className="btn btn-secondary btn-width-200 search-submit" 
   onClick={this.handleSubmit} >
     Search

</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need to understand is, how to achieve route using `react-router` API. Basically you can configure it on two API, `browserHistory` and `hashHistory`. ([link](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md))

So, in otherword, by calling `browserHistory.push('/booking/search')` or `hashHistory.push('/booking/search')` you should be able to navigate between routes.

There is redux version also available, just in case if you want to manage your navigation via some action dispatch (though it is not necessary). [Link](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux)

For more info: [Programmatically navigate using react router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the push router method in external Function instead of using `Link`. For example:

```
redirectFunction() {
 this.handleSubmit()
 router.push({
  to: '/booking/search',
  query: this.state.filters
 })
}

render () {
  <div 
   className="btn btn-secondary btn-width-200 search-submit" 
   onClick={this.redirectFunction.bind(this)}>
     Search 
  </div>
}
```